# Execution default-build of goal org.kie:kie-maven-plugin:8.44.0.Final:build failed

Tags: drools, rules, rule-engine

I'm trying to build my drool project ( 8.44.0.Final and jdk-11.0.18.10-hotspot) its getting failed  .When i try to in eclipse its working fine . But When build its throwing error. I have enabled the model generation to make it as pre comlpied to increase the performance.

`pom.xml`

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.kie</groupId>
    <artifactId>kie-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${drools.version}</version>
    <extensions>true</extensions>
    <configuration>
        <generateModel>YES</generateModel>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

My Rule

```
rule "Validate Data"

lock-on-active true
salience 10
when
      $fact: Fact ( $id: getRequest().getId() != null &&
      $fId: Util.getFunctionId(getRequest().getData()) !=  null
)
then

String warningMessage = "Tetsing";
$fact.addError("Warning_Content_Type", warningMessage, ErrorDisplaySettings.ONLY_ERROR);  
update($fact);

end
```

Java method  - This method will return  0 or int value

```java
public static int getFunctionId(List<Data> data) {
    int returnValue = 0;

    try {
        if (data == null || data.size() == 0)
            return returnValue;
    
        Data data = data.get(0);
        List<DomainData> functions = data.getFunctions();

        if (functions != null && functions.size() > 0) {
            DomainData function = functions.get(0);
            returnValue = function.getId();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.debug("getPrimaryFunctionId : " + e.getMessage());
    }
    return returnValue;
}
```

Error:

```
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution default-build of goal org.kie:kie-maven-plugin:8.44.0.Final:build failed: Unable to create KieModule, Errors Existed: \[Message \[id=1, kieBase=mutation, level=ERROR, path=com/xx/xx/rules/xx/validation/Function.drl, line=13, column=0
text=Predicate 'nullnull' must be a Boolean expression\]\]
```

Previously i used 7.24.0.Final version its working as expected .. but after changing to 8.44.0.Final its failing. I'm not sure why its failing .

Comment: If it worked in 7.24 and fails in 8.44 then it stands to reason that something has changed. Unfortunately you've not shared your dependencies or how you upgraded to the newer major version. (There's a number of non-backwards-compatible changes between these two versions.)